# Dotfuscator and 8.1 AppxBundles

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, obfuscation, windows-8.1, dotfuscator

I am attempting to obfuscate my Windows Store 8.1 Appxbundles. I am using Dotfuscator Professional to do this. It does not accept the Appxbundle file extension, so I unzipped the Appxbundle to retrieve the .appx package inside.

I then received this error:

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime_dot'  Key being added: 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime_dot'
Build Error.
```

I noticed that the `ildasm` executable dotfuscator was using was wrong, so I added a project property to force it to use the 4.5.1/8.1 ildasm. Unfortunately, I am receiving the same error.

Does anyone know what is causing this error? Or what the next step is after `ildasm`, so I can investigate it?

Edit: Also, I'm using the most recent version of Dotfuscator Professional, 4.10.2.

Comment: But, doesn't Dotfuscator officially support WinRT apps? (I'm surprised you'd need to unzip the bundle manually).

Comment: It's true, they support Windows Store apps, but that was before the release of Windows 8.1 in which they changed how the apps are packaged in some cases (such as where the developer includes multiple language resources or scaled resources, of which we do). They package each chunk individually in an 'AppxBundle', which is currently unsupported by the most recent version.

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket with them? Win 8.1 and VS 2013 was hardly a surprise.

Comment: I posted on the forums, which I believe they check (they've opened a ticket for me in the past after posting on the forums). I'd bet money that they're about to release a new version to support 8.1, I'm just so surprised it's this long after release. I was hoping someone would have a hack that can act as a stop-gap or could help me with the unzipping hack (maybe even someone from PreEmptive).

Comment: (Well, there are only 5 followers of the dotfuscator tag here currently ..., so the support ticket probably is your best bet still).

Comment: A couple of them are PreEmptive employees though, so I was hoping to reach them from a couple of angles.

Comment: I dare say that we (developers and support personnel) check stackoverflow pretty often :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the official response from PreEmptive (makers of Dotfuscator):  We’re planning a release this week that will support Win 8.1 .NET desktop apps and .NET 4.5.1 apps created with VS 2013.  We’re expecting to include support for Windows Store 8.1 apps and appxbundles specifically in our next planned release, which we’re estimating will be in January.  We’ve started looking into manual workarounds for appxbundles but the possibilities we’ve investigated so far look like they will be complicated.

Comment: Also:  The error message in the initial post should be addressed in the next release of Dotfuscator, due out this week.